# Complexity of two imbricated loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have this algorithm (in `c` code for convenience):

```
int algo(int *T, int size)
{
   int n = 0;

   for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
       for (int j = i; j < size; j++) {
           n += (T[i] * T[j]);
       }
   }

   return n;
}
```

What is this algorithm's time complexity?

My bet is it is `n * log (n)` since we have two imbricated iterations on the `size` length one time, and on`size - i` the second time, but I am not sure.

A formal proof of the complexity is welcome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an O(N<sup>2</sup>) algorithm.

- First iteration of the outer loop runs N-1 times
- Second iteration of the outer loop runs N-2 times
- Third iteration of the outer loop runs N-3 times
- ...
- Last iteration of the outer loop runs 1 time

The total number of times is (N)+(N-1)+(N-2)+...+1, which is the [sum of arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum). The formula for computing the sum is N*(N-1)/2, which is O(N<sup>2</sup>).